# Meteor subscription doesn't refresh despite WaitOn

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-publications

I'm using Iron Router. I have a RouterController that looks something like this:

```
var loggedInUserController = RouteController.extend({
    layoutTemplate: "GenericLayout",
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe("TheDataINeed");
    }
});
```

And I have a route defined which uses this controller to wait for the 'TheDataINeed':

```
Router.route("/myapp", {
    name: "Landing",
    controller: loggedInUserController,
    data: function () {
        if(this.ready()){
            return {content: "page-landing"};
        }
    }
});
```

Now, the problem is the data I am subscribed to is conditional: meaning, depending on the user's role, I publish different data, like so:

```
   if (!Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'subscribed') ) {
        return [
            myData.getElements({}, { fields: { _id: 1, title: 1}, limit: 5 })
        ];
    } else {
        return [
            myData.getElements({}, { fields: { _id: 1, title: 1} })
        ];
    }
```

When the user's role is not 'subscribed', I limit the published data to 5 elements.

The problem is publishing is not reactive, so when the user changes his role for the first time to 'subscribed' and I navigate to my route ("/myapp"), the user still sees the limited number of elements instead of all of them.

Is there a way to manually re-trigger the subscription when I am loading this route? If possible, I'd like to do this without adding new packages to my app.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about that approach but can you try to set session value in route instead of subscription code. Then in a file on client side where your subscriptions are you can wrap `Meteor.subscribe("TheDataINeed")` in `Tracker.autorun` and have a session as a subscription parameter. Every time that session value is changed autorun will rerun subscription and it will return you data based on a new value.